kernel probes shows wrong returned data
Unfortunately the title might not be the best for describing the problem.
I'm learning Linux kernel programming and when I was excited when it came to kprobe and kretprobe, but I start to experience some strange(to my very low knowledge of the matter) behavior soon. Let me explain...
I installed kretprobe on __x64_sys_getdents64, my final goal is to replicate some of the code I saw online for hiding files and directories in Linux but using kernel probes.
The getdents prototype is,
long syscall(SYS_getdents, unsigned int fd, struct linux_dirent *dirp,
                    unsigned int count);

and on success it returns the number of bytes read is returned.
Fun Facts

In kretprobe return handler we don't have access to the function arguments, only the return value, and we can also change the return value.
In kretprobe entry handler, we have access function arguments

So, kprobe post handler, I keep some information like dirp pointer, allocate some memory and read dirp which at this point supposed to be the list of files to allocated buffer on heap.
// Global variables
struct linux_dirent64 *g_dirp = NULL;
unsigned long g_count = GETDENTS_COUNT_DUMMY;
char* g_kdirp_buf = NULL;
int g_is_copied = 0;

Part of kretprobe entry handler,
    g_dirp = dirp;
    g_count = count;
    g_kdirp_buf = kzalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (g_kdirp_buf == NULL)
    {
        printk("ERR kmalloc() failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (copy_from_user(g_kdirp_buf, dirp, count))
    {
        printk("ERR copy_from_user() failed!\n");
        kfree(g_kdirp_buf);
        return 0;
    }

In kretprobe return handler I check if the return value is bigger than 0, meaning the function returned X number of bytes, then I read the data that is already kept for us in kprobe post handler.
    long ret;
    ret = regs_return_value(regs);
    // Technically none-zero return value means there should be some data in dirp
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        unsigned long offset = 0;
        struct linux_dirent64 *d;
        d = (struct linux_dirent64 *)(g_kdirp_buf + offset);
    }

But when I try to read a file from the data we kept in kprobe post handler, there is not file available! What I observe is as follow,

When return value is none zero, there is no file in dirp
When the return value is 0, then I get list of files in dirp

Below is the full code for the kernel module(the following code is messy and violates every best practice in kernel programming world, sorry for that),
Kernel module,
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#define ROOTKIT_PATTERN                 "example.txt"
#define GETDENTS_COUNT_DUMMY            9999888221

struct linux_dirent
{
    unsigned long   d_ino;
    unsigned long   d_off;
    unsigned short  d_reclen;
    char            d_name[];
};

struct linux_dirent64
{
    uint64_t        d_ino;
    int64_t         d_off;
    unsigned short  d_reclen;
    unsigned char   d_type;
    char            d_name[];
};

spinlock_t supp_len_lock;

struct linux_dirent64 *g_dirp = NULL;
unsigned long g_count = GETDENTS_COUNT_DUMMY;
char* g_kdirp_buf = NULL;
int g_is_copied = 0;

static int handler_entry(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
#if IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_X86_64)
    // int fd = ((struct pt_regs*)regs->di)->di;
    void *dirv = (void *)((struct pt_regs*)regs->di)->si;
    struct linux_dirent64 *dirp = (struct linux_dirent64 *)dirv;
    unsigned long count = ((struct pt_regs*)regs->di)->dx;
#elif IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_ARM64)
    // int fd = ((struct pt_regs*)regs->regs[1])->regs[0];
    void *dirv = (void *)((struct pt_regs*)regs->regs[1])->regs[1];
    struct linux_dirent64 *dirp = (struct linux_dirent64 *)dirv;
    unsigned long count = ((struct pt_regs*)regs[1])->regs[2];
#endif

    g_dirp = dirp;
    g_count = count;
    g_kdirp_buf = kzalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (g_kdirp_buf == NULL)
    {
        printk("ERR kmalloc() failed!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (copy_from_user(g_kdirp_buf, dirp, count))
    {
        printk("ERR copy_from_user() failed!\n");
        kfree(g_kdirp_buf);
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int handler_ret(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    long ret;

    if ((g_dirp == NULL) || (g_kdirp_buf == NULL) || (g_count == GETDENTS_COUNT_DUMMY))
    {
        printk("[handler_ret]\t\tINITIALIZATION FAILED\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ret = regs_return_value(regs);


    if (ret != 0)
    {
        unsigned long offset = 0;
        struct linux_dirent64 *d;
        d = (struct linux_dirent64 *)(g_kdirp_buf + offset);
        printk("%s\n", d->d_name);
    }

    if (g_kdirp_buf != NULL)
    {
        kfree(g_kdirp_buf);
    }

    return 0;
}

static struct kretprobe kretprobe = {
    .handler = handler_ret,
    .entry_handler = handler_entry,
    .kp.symbol_name = "__x64_sys_getdents64"
};


static int __init kretprobe_init(void)
{
    spin_lock_init(&supp_len_lock);

    register_kretprobe(&kretprobe);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit kretprobe_exit(void)
{

    unregister_kretprobe(&kretprobe);
}

module_init(kretprobe_init)
module_exit(kretprobe_exit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

The Makefile,
obj-m += hidproc.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

To my understanding, I should get a file name in dmesg, but I just get an empty entry!
When the ret value is equal to 0 then dirp is populated with file names!

Am I doing anything wrong in my code? Or maybe the logic is wrong!
Why I do not get data when the return value is more than zero?

Any clue is welcome.
Thanks,
Jelal

The .entry_handler function is executed at the beginning of the hooked function. So copy_from_user called from handler_entry copies content of dirp which has not yet modified by the SYS_getdents. For obtain final content of dirp, you need to call copy_from_user in handler_ret instead.

So I just keep the pointer from entry handler and do the copy_from_user() in return handler? Am I even allowed to call copy_from_user() or  copy_to_user() from inside kretprobe return handler?

"In kretprobe return handler we don't have access to the function arguments" - This is not quite true. You have access to the function's arguments via regs parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686393/get-a-probed-functions-arguments-in-the-entry-handler-of-a-kretprobe. Also, for transfer data from .entry_handler to .handler instead of global variables it is better to utilize kretprobe_instance structure. Look how .data_size used in other code.

"Am I even allowed to call copy_from_user() or copy_to_user() from inside kretprobe return handler?" - I don't find any constraints in using sleep-able functions inside kprobes.

going to try this right now! thanks

@Tsyvarev this worked. If you post an answer I will mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Thanks to @Tsyvarev I could find the solution. I moved the reading to the ret handler, so when I copy_from_user the actual syscall is being called and data is available.
Cheers
