Modifying (stealing) Linux syscalls using kprobe
I am trying to steal the statx syscall on Linux 6.8 and to modify the returning arguments.
However, when attemp to load the module, I got a BUG about NULL pointer deference at line
r = strncpy_from_user(path, (char __user *)user_regs->si, 128);

Here is my code:
I use this question (Cannot read syscall arguments from a kprobe handler).
But I did manage to deal with the argument.
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h> 

MODULE_VERSION("v.0");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Flavien <flav> ASTRAUD <flav@epita.fr>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("ex. pour interception d'un syscall");

static int m_statx(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    long r = 0;
    char path[128];
    struct pt_regs *user_regs = (struct pt_regs *)regs->di;
    struct statx statxbuf; // (struct statx *) regs->r8;

    r = strncpy_from_user(path, (char __user *)user_regs->si, 128);
    
    r = copy_from_user(&statxbuf, (struct statx *)user_regs->r8,
               sizeof (struct statx));

    pr_info("STATX_V3 %s size=%lld\n", path, statxbuf.stx_size);

    statxbuf.stx_size = 42;

    r = copy_to_user((struct statx *)user_regs->r8,
             &statxbuf, sizeof(statxbuf));

    return 0;
}

static struct kretprobe kret = { 
    //  .symbol_name = "__x64_sys_statx", 
    .handler = m_statx,
};

static int override_statx(void)
{
    kret.kp.symbol_name = "__x64_sys_statx";
    if (register_kretprobe(&kret) < 0) 
        return 0; 
    return 0;
}

static void pullback_syscall(void)
{
    unregister_kretprobe(&kret);
    
    return;
}

static int __init kstatx_init(void)
{
    pr_info("kstatx INIT\n=============\n");

    override_statx();

    return 0;
}

static void __exit kstatx_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("kstatx END\n=============\n"); 
    
    pullback_syscall();
}

module_init(kstatx_init);
module_exit(kstatx_exit);



@Tsyvarev It's only for teaching matter ; I try with statx but I could do it with other syscall.

In this case, when I dont touch path but only statxbuf.stx_size it must work ; but it does not

Have you tried to run your test case (ls -l) under the strace utility? It will show you which exact system calls are actually executed. Among those, you could search for statx syscalls and inspect their parameters. E.g. for me strace shows the resulted stx_size value, so you could compare it with your expectations.

@Tsyvarev I do it ; It shows me the unmodify value

Yes, the question is much better now. But ... post-handler doesn't look as a proper mechanism for execute your code after the system call returns. You place your kprobe at the very first instruction of the statx system call, so post-handler is executed after given instruction, not after the entire function. For execute your code after the function, use kretprobe and its .handler field.

@Tsyvarev I try to get the argument : like that struct pt_regs *user_regs = (struct pt_regs *)regs->di; But the module crahes at loading ? I cant find how to make it

"Module crashing" is not a problem description sufficient for solving the problem. Have you checked the call stack in the crash message? Which line of your code is executed according to that call stack? And so on. If you have modified your code, then update the question post with the actual code.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Tsyvarev The module crashes on r = strncpy_from_user(path, (char __user *)user_regs->si, 128);
`"BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address"

So, what do you want to achieve in your new code with the post-handler? If you want to just print some values of a syscall, then use pre-handler, as in the question you refer to. If you want to modify result of the function, then use kretprobe. Using a random kind of the kprobe is not a way for programming in the kernel.

@Tsyvarev I mis update my code last time ; I have follow your advice and I use kretprobe but I did not manage

A handler for kretprobe doesn't have access to the function's arguments: its regs argument contains registers upon function's returning, not the ones upon function's entering. But those arguments could be extracted in the pre-handler, and passed via kretprobe_instance argument. See that my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619294/kernel-probes-shows-wrong-returned-data#comment138611899_78619294

Here the solution with the help of @tsyvarev
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h> 

MODULE_VERSION("v.0");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("flav <flav@epita.fr>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("ex. pour interception d'un syscall");

struct my_data {
    char *ppath;
    struct statx *s_statx;
};

static int m_statx_pre(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct my_data *data;
    char *ppath;

    pr_info("STATX entry\n");
    ppath = (char *)((struct pt_regs *)regs->di)->si;
    struct statx *statx = (struct statx *)((struct pt_regs *)regs->di)->r8;

    data = (struct my_data *)ri->data;
    data->s_statx = statx;
    data->ppath = ppath;

    return 0;
}

static int m_statx(struct kretprobe_instance *ri, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    
    struct my_data *data;
    
    
    
    long r = 0;
    char path[128];

    struct statx statxbuf;

    data = (struct my_data *)ri->data;
    r = strncpy_from_user(path, data->ppath, 128);
    
    r = copy_from_user(&statxbuf, data->s_statx, sizeof (struct statx));

    pr_info("STATX_V3 %s size=%lld\n", path, statxbuf.stx_size);
    pr_info("STATX_ret: [%s]\n", path);


    statxbuf.stx_size = 42;
    statxbuf.stx_uid = 42;
    statxbuf.stx_gid = 42;

    r = copy_to_user(data->ppath, path, strlen(path)+1);
    r = copy_to_user(data->s_statx, &statxbuf, sizeof(statxbuf));

    return 0;
}

static struct kretprobe kret = { 
    .handler = m_statx,
    .entry_handler = m_statx_pre,
    .data_size = sizeof (struct my_data),
};

static int override_statx(void)
{
    kret.kp.symbol_name = "__x64_sys_statx";
    if (register_kretprobe(&kret) < 0) 
        return 0; 
    return 0;
}

static void pullback_syscall(void)
{
    unregister_kretprobe(&kret);
    
    return;
}

static int __init kstatx_init(void)
{
    pr_info("kstatx INIT\n=============\n");

    override_statx();

    return 0;
}

static void __exit kstatx_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("kstatx END\n=============\n"); 
    
    pullback_syscall();
}

module_init(kstatx_init);
module_exit(kstatx_exit);

Without the module :
# stat kparm.ko 
  File: kparm.ko
  Size: 302816          Blocks: 592        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 252,0   Inode: 393542      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)

# ls -ln kparm.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 302816 Oct  7 10:23 kparm.ko

With the module :
# stat kparm.ko 
  File: kparm.ko
  Size: 42              Blocks: 592        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 252,0   Inode: 393542      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (   42/    _apt)   Gid: (   42/  shadow)

# ls -ln kparm.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 42 42 42 Oct  7 10:23 kparm.ko


You have removed modification of read-only parameter pathname from the question, but have added it to the answer's code. Really?!

@Tsyvarev Hum ! ok ; so Should I change the question or answer?


From the code in the question post remove all manipulations with path. Instead, demonstrate manipulations with stat_ctx field. 2. Update description in the question post to correspond with the code. (Your last code causes NULL pointer dereference, but current description tells about incorrect size observed.) 3. From the code in the answer post remove all manipulations with path.

